# How to extract a singular point from a clumped set of cooridinate points?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, buffer

I have a set of coordinates and they represent all the same point but due to the GPS error they are spaced apart. What I want to do is use a valid method to get a singular point out of the clump of points. Perhaps using a buffer zone to encompass all points then the center of the object?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Ooops sorry should have mentioned that - QGIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If necessary, create groups with common IDs, then dissolve by that ID, then create centroids for your dissolved clusters.